# Pundit authorize mongodb aggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, mongodb, mongoid, pundit

I am using Pundit to authorize a model in my controller:

```
@board = authorize Board.find(id)
```

However, I have a `full()` method on my model that calls a mongodb aggregation and returns json. If I try to authorize that I get the error:

`unable to find policy 'HashPolicy' for ... (object)`

This is because Pundit expects an `active_record` model to authorize.

I am currently getting around this my first authorizing the `Board.find(id)`, and then making a second db call to get the aggregation. This is obviously impractical.

Is there any way I can get Pundit to accept the json object? Or is there a way for me to get the  original object back from my aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to explicitly set the `policy_class` if the record is not an active record object:

`@board = authorize Board.find(id), policy_class: BoardPolicy`